Split-Species sensitivity distributions in R
I would like to generate plot showing the Species sensitivity distribution (SSD) for each trophic level per chemical. I am able to do one single SSD including all trophic levels but not separately for Algae, Fish and Invertebrates.
My data contains toxicity data for Chloryprifos (CAS 2921-88-2) and Algae, Fish and  Invertebrates. With my loop i am able to do the normal SSD including all trophic levels.
This is my loop:
for (i in acute.mean$cas){ # for each chemical

print(i)

#Create dump subsets for the loop and trophic level  
dump_fish <- unique.acute.mean[cas == i & trophic_level == "fish"]
dump_invert <- unique.acute.mean[cas == i & trophic_level == "invert"]
dump_algae <- unique.acute.mean[cas == i & trophic_level == "algae"]

#Create different ssd.fits for trophic level  
ssd.fits.fish <- ssd_fit_dists(dump_fish, left = "Conc",
dists = c("llogis", "gamma", "lnorm", "gompertz",
"lgumbel", "weibull", "burrIII3",
"invpareto", "llogis_llogis",
"lnorm_lnorm"))

ssd.fits.invert <- ssd_fit_dists(dump_invert, left = "Conc",
dists = c("llogis", "gamma", "lnorm", "gompertz",
"lgumbel", "weibull", "burrIII3",
"invpareto", "llogis_llogis",
"lnorm_lnorm"))

ssd.fits.algae <- ssd_fit_dists(dump_algae, left = "Conc",
dists = c("llogis", "gamma", "lnorm", "gompertz",
"lgumbel", "weibull", "burrIII3",
"invpareto", "llogis_llogis",
"lnorm_lnorm"))

#Save GoF for each trophic level
ssd.gof_fits_fish <- ssd_gof(ssd.fits.fish) # Save the goodness of fit statistics
ssd.gof_fits_invert <- ssd_gof(ssd.fits.invert)
ssd.gof_fits_algae <- ssd_gof(ssd.fits.algae)

print("prepredict")

#Save distributions chosen for each trophic level
chosen_dist_fish <- ssd.gof_fits_fish %\>% # Choose the best fit distribution by
filter(aicc==min(aicc)) # finding the minimum aicc
chosen_dist_invert <- ssd.gof_fits_invert %\>%
filter(aicc==min(aicc))
chosen_dist_algae <- ssd.gof_fits_algae %\>%
filter(aicc==min(aicc))

#Save final fit
final.fit.fish <- ssd_fit_dists(dump_fish, dists = chosen_dist_fish$dist)
final.fit.invert <- ssd_fit_dists(dump_invert, dists = chosen_dist_invert$dist)
final.fit.algae <- ssd_fit_dists(dump_algae, dists = chosen_dist_algae$dist)

#Set.seed is a random number geneation
set.seed(99)

#Derivation of the HC5 of the dataset
hc5.fish <- ssd_hc(final.fit.fish, ci = T, nboot = 100)
hc5.invert <- ssd_hc(final.fit.invert, ci = T, nboot = 100)
hc5.algae <- ssd_hc(final.fit.algae, ci = T, nboot = 100)

# Use the chosen distribution only

final.predict.fish <- predict(final.fit.fish, ci = T, nboot = 100) # generate the final    predictions
final.predict.invert <- predict(final.fit.invert, ci = T, nboot = 100)
final.predict.algae <- predict(final.fit.algae, ci = T, nboot = 100)

print("afterpredict")

plotdata.fish <- dump_fish # create a separate plot data frame
plotdata.invert <- dump_invert
plotdata.algae <- dump_algae

final.plot <- ssd_plot(plotdata, final.predict,
color = "trophic_level",
xlab = "Concentration (ug/L)", ribbon = TRUE) +
expand_limits(x = 10e4) +
ggtitle(paste("(1) Acute Species Sensitivity distribution for", i, sep = " ")) +
scale_colour_ssd()

ggsave(filename = paste("PDF/SSD for",i, ".pdf", sep = ""),
plot = final.plot)
    }

I tried to add to the ssd_plot another one with a different trophic level but output from R says i cannot add another ggplot.
